# Design pattern to rewrite a Java class from an API

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have to use the EWS Java API to call Exchange Server.
In this API, there is Task class which have more than 20-30 getters of different properties.
In our company, we will use only 4-5 properties; idem for Contacts and Appointment.

In my opinion, I consider it may be more practical to write a mini-API so the developers can be found easier the 4-5 properties they have to use for the three Items (Appointments, Task, Contact).

The ExtendedTask I've just created must be extended the Task class from the original API ? If yes, do i have to create the 4-5 attributes in the ExtendedTask because it is rendundant with the parent class ?!

What would you do if you were me ? Use the original class ? Create a subclass ? Create another class which don't extend the Task class ?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Why would you extend the original class? It won't give you what you want since the getters are inherited. If you only know about inheritance and not about composition, you probably shouldn't be trying to "help" your fellow developers.

Comment: Yes, it's right. Composition must be more useful here, i didn't think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Use Facade pattern. Create a class that encapsulates all the logic that your users would be needing in order to use your 3 Task-related actions (Appointments, Task, Contact).

Using this "Facade" class would hide the actual implementation logic (original API) from the end users, since majority of the API is not used.

```
//pseudo code

class MyAPIFacade {

  @Inject 
  OriginalAPI api;

  public Task getTask() {
    return api.getTask();
  }

  public Appointments getAppointments() {
    return api.getAppointments();
  }

  public Contact getContact() {
    return api.getContact();
  }
```

}